# "As it is only people who name the act of naming and re-naming is ..."

Tags: meaning

> As it is only people who name the act of naming and re-naming is always in favor of the unconcious desire and concious self-interest of those doing the naming.
>
> — [Understanding Branding in Higher Education: Marketing Identities](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mnQ7DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA82&lpg=PA82&dq=%22only%20people%20who%20name%20the%20act%20of%20naming%20and%20re-naming%22&source=bl&ots=P0RYlW87gQ&sig=6aD9pGHYO7sko7eWpTX8FuQqCcU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjd7MvAq8ncAhWKE4gKHc8uC48Q6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22only%20people%20who%20name%20the%20act%20of%20naming%20and%20re-naming%22&f=false)

Regarding *...is always*" does *is* refer to *people who name...*?

Comment: Apparently [a quote](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mnQ7DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA82&lpg=PA82&dq=%22only+people+who+name+the+act+of+naming+and+re-naming%22&source=bl&ots=P0RYlW87gQ&sig=6aD9pGHYO7sko7eWpTX8FuQqCcU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjd7MvAq8ncAhWKE4gKHc8uC48Q6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22only%20people%20who%20name%20the%20act%20of%20naming%20and%20re-naming%22&f=false)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused as to what you're asking.

Comment: Always refers to The act of renaming, not the people.

Comment: Following k1eran's edit this question is clear and on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a comma should make it clear that "always" refers to "the act":

> As it is only people who name, the act of naming and renaming is
>   always in favor of the unconscious desire and conscious self-interest
>   of those doing the naming.

Breaking the sentence further:

> As it is only people who name, the act of naming and renaming | is
>   always in favor of | the unconscious desire and conscious
>   self-interest | of those doing the naming.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer was useful. Now I can understand the meaning.